# Flutter Firebase field string matching

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, encoding

So I'm creating this flutter project where I want to match 2 field from a different collection in firebase how should I do that? Like if the first data from the 1st field matches the data from the 2nd field return true

[here it the example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duXw4.png)
[- and here is the 2nd example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JJUi.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but are you asking how to query Firestore? If so: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Yeah its somewhat like that but I want to match 2 fields from a different collection if the 2 field matches the same data return true

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries can only order/filter on data that is inside each document that they actually return. There is no way to order/filter in any value in another document, whether present in the results or not.

Usually you'll want to modify your data model to your use-case, typically by adding more data that allows this specific query. This is actually quite common in NoSQL databases, where you often end up expanding your data model to allow for specific use-cases. To learn more about data modeling in NoSQL databases, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching Todd's video series [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).